# AVAssetExportSession videoComposition not showing all frames in video

Tags: ios, swift, avassetexportsession, avasset, avmutablecomposition

I'm making video from an array of UIImages. I did that successfully & all the images are showing on the video. I'm using AVAssetExportSession to export the video which is also working except when I'm using AVAssetExportSession videoComposition property the video only shows the first image. Here is my code:

```
func mergeAudioVideoFiles(videoUrl:NSURL, audioUrl:NSURL)->NSURL
{
    let mixComposition : AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    var mutableCompositionVideoTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
    var mutableCompositionAudioTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
    let totalVideoCompositionInstruction : AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()


    //start merge

    let aVideoAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(URL: videoUrl)
    let aAudioAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(URL: audioUrl)

    mutableCompositionVideoTrack.append(mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    mutableCompositionAudioTrack.append( mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    let aVideoAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aVideoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
    let aAudioAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aAudioAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]
    do{
        try mutableCompositionVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), ofTrack: aVideoAssetTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)

        try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), ofTrack: aAudioAssetTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)    
    }catch{

    }
    print("\nslide duraition:\(CMTimeGetSeconds(aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration))\n")
    totalVideoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration )

    let mutableVideoComposition : AVMutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(propertiesOfAsset: aVideoAsset)
    mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration
    mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(1280,720)

    //find your video on this URl
    let savePathUrl : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("pandorarofinalist.mov"))

    // 4. Add subtitles (we call it theme)
    let insertTime = kCMTimeZero
    //let endTime = aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration
    //let range = self.totalFrameDuration
    //let themeVideoComposition : AVMutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(propertiesOfAsset: aVideoAsset)
    // 4.2 - Create an AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction for the video track and fix the orientation.

    let videolayerInstruction : AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: aVideoAssetTrack)
    totalVideoCompositionInstruction.layerInstructions = NSArray(array: [videolayerInstruction]) as! [AVVideoCompositionLayerInstruction]
    mutableVideoComposition.instructions = NSArray(array: [totalVideoCompositionInstruction]) as! [AVVideoCompositionInstructionProtocol]

    //mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].preferredTransform
    videolayerInstruction.setTransform(mutableCompositionVideoTrack[0].preferredTransform, atTime: insertTime)
    //videolayerInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, atTime: endTime)

    // 4.3 - Add instructions


   // mutableVideoComposition.renderScale = 1.0
    //themeVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(aVideoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width, aVideoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height)
   //themeVideoComposition.frameDuration = self.totalFrameDuration

    // add text

    let title = String("my video")

    let titleLayer = CATextLayer()
    titleLayer.string = title
    titleLayer.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: aVideoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width, height: 100)
    let fontName: CFStringRef = "Helvetica-Bold"
    let fontSize = CGFloat(50)
    titleLayer.font = CTFontCreateWithName(fontName, fontSize, nil)
    titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
    titleLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor

    let backgroundLayer = CALayer()
    backgroundLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: aVideoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width, height: aVideoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height)
    backgroundLayer.masksToBounds = true
    backgroundLayer.addSublayer(titleLayer)

    // 2. set parent layer and video layer

    let parentLayer = CALayer()
    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    parentLayer.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: aVideoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width, height: aVideoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height)
    videoLayer.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: aVideoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width, height: aVideoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(backgroundLayer)

    //backgroundLayer.opacity = 1.0

    // 3. make animation

    mutableVideoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, inLayer: parentLayer)

    // Remove the file if it already exists (merger does not overwrite)

    do{
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        try fileManager.removeItemAtURL(savePathUrl)
    }catch{
    }

    let assetExport: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    assetExport.outputURL = savePathUrl
    assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    assetExport.videoComposition = mutableVideoComposition

    assetExport.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler { () -> Void in
        switch assetExport.status {

        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed:

            PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(savePathUrl)
            }) { success, error in
                if !success {
                    print("Error saving video: \(error)")
                }
            }

            //Uncomment this if u want to store your video in asset

            //let assetsLib = ALAssetsLibrary()
            //assetsLib.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(savePathUrl, completionBlock: nil)

            print("success")
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
            print("failed \(assetExport.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
            print("cancelled \(assetExport.error)")
        default:
            print("complete")
        }
    }

    return savePathUrl
}
```

The problem is that line **assetExport.videoComposition = mutableVideoComposition** If i omit this line the output video is just fine. But if I add this line the output video only shows the first image that I've added for the video. I have to set videoComposition cause I'm adding title text to the video which I've added as CALayer. I'm using swift 2.2 for my project. Any help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: This is a bug with AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool please check this post and all related posts http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=swift%20AVAssetWriter

Comment: However I have not managed to implement a solution

Comment: No I didn't find any solution to this. Alternatively I did the following: Add the title text with the selected images which generate new image containing text & then with the output images the desired video was created. In the process I omitted the line that causes problem.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the problem is this line:

`mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration`

`frameDuration` is supposed to represent the duration of a single frame in the video, not the total duration of the video. The line above makes it so one frame of the video lasts the duration of the original video track, so you're only going to see one frame, as if it was a still image.

For a 30fps video, you should set frameDuration to 1/30th of a second, like this:

**`mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30)`**

---

Warning: Be careful not to use the other init method `CMTime(seconds: 1.0, preferredTimescale: 30)`, because that will make your frameDuration 1 second.